# Clarification on DH groups

Tags: vulnerability, diffie-hellman, logjam

Nikto reports the following via the "ssl-dh-params" NSE script:

```
Check results:
|       WEAK DH GROUP 1
|             Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
|             Modulus Type: Safe prime
|             Modulus Source: mod_ssl 2.2.x/1024-bit MODP group with safe prime modulus
|             Modulus Length: 1024
|             Generator Length: 8
|             Public Key Length: 1024
```

Why is the DH group reported as "WEAK DH GROUP 1" when Group 1 should have a modulus length of 768 [according to sources such as this](http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/wsm/xtm_11/en-us/content/en-us/bovpn/manual/diffie_hellman_c.html)? This, as you can see is 1024 which should be Group 2.